# Getting an error when running John The Ripper on 7zip file

Tags: john-the-ripper, 7zip

I've never really worked with this tool, John Jumbo 1.9. I'm just curious since people say 7zip is a secure way of encrypting files, so I wanted to try it myself. Anyways, I encrypted a file with 7z, and installed `john-jumbo` on my machine running macOS Catalina. I wanted to get the hash of the file, so I ran `john 7z2john.pl file.7z > ~/Desktop/file.hash` attempting to get the hash of the file. However, when I ran it, I got the following error:

```
Warning: detected hash type "HMAC-SHA256", but the string is also recognized as "HMAC-SHA512"
Use the "--format=HMAC-SHA512" option to force loading these as that type instead
Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading file.7z
oracle: Input file is not UTF-8. Please use --input-enc to specify a codepage.
Warning: only loading hashes of type "HMAC-SHA256", but also saw type "HMAC-SHA224"
Use the "--format=HMAC-SHA224" option to force loading hashes of that type instead
Error: UTF-16 BOM seen in input file.
```

After some testing and stuff, it said, "UTF-16" is not supported, but I think I read in the documentation that UTF-16 is supported, so now I am confused.